# What role does ServiceName play in Service-Designers InitializeComponent() method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I'm currently working on a Windows Service called PrintWatcher. This name is also set in the serviceInstaller properties window. The service works fine and the name is correctly displayed in the task managers 'Services' tab.
However, in the ServiceClass Designer, I found the following:

```
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.ServiceName = "Service1";
        }
```

Which impact does assigning "Service1" to this.ServiceName have on the service? This name is nowhere displayed, but modifying it manually is not adviced as written in the summary above.
Where else should the name be set?

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, a windows service class inherited from the `ServiceBase` Class.

Therefore, we need to know more about [ServiceBase.ServiceName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.servicename?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

**The ServiceName identifies the service to the Service Control Manager.**

There is a sentence in the above link to describe the function of the ServiceName.

Also, it says that `ServiceBase.ServiceName` must be be identical to `ServiceInstaller.ServiceName`.(That is the reason that we don't suggest that you change the ServiceName)

Finally, it will be better for you to look at the Remarks in the first link to know more about the ServiceName property.